# Ты думаешь (,) мы дадим тебе отдыхать?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, недопустимая-метка, правила

Ставится ли запятая после слова "думаешь"? Если нет, то по каким правилам русского языка это можно объяснить?

Comment: грамматические основы "ты думаешь" и "мы дадим" намекают, что это бессоюзное, а лучше просто сложное предложение, так что нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Это такая бессоюзная связь предложений, когда между частями можно вставить изъяснительный союз ‟что”. Про это есть в справочнике Розенталя [(пункт 3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150). Там говорится, что ставится двоеточие, если есть предупредительная интонация. Вот несколько таких примеров:

> С беспокойством я выпрыгнул из кибитки и вижу: матушка встречает меня на крыльце с видом глубокого огорчения (П.).
> Он видел: вставала земля из пепла, непокорённая земля (Горб.).
> Люди знали: где-то, очень далеко от них, идёт война (Аж).

Также в справочнике есть примечание о том, что если нет предупредительной интонации, то ставится запятая, и ваше предложение как раз такое.

**Минутка критики справочника Розенталя.**

В этом пункте можно заметить одну ошибку, а также одну значимую кривость.

Там в примечании есть такие строки:

> Если вторая часть — предложение неполное, то перед ней может ставиться тире: Я думал — волк.

Когда человек, писавший пособие, встретил это предложение, то он назвал первое, что придёт в голову – неполное предложение. Мы видим, насколько сильно старались люди при написании этого справочника – просто называли первое, что придёт в голову, и писали это. На самом деле тут стоит тире по причине контрастной паузы (резкая смена событий или резкая эмоциональная смена).

Что касается кривости, примечание начинается так:

> Примечание. При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: Слышу, земля задрожала (Н.).

В приведённом примере нет предупредительной паузы, но есть контрастная пауза, и наличие такой паузы введёт человека в недоумение. Следовало бы подобрать другой пример для примера отсутствия предупредительной паузы.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143124/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.